# Publish my own CocoaPod Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm about to create a cocoaPod for a small iOS Framework for our customer. I have 2 questions about it.

1) I'm depending on another framework that is also available via cocoaPod. Could it happen that the original author removes the lib and therefor could kill my framework as well or is this secured?

2) I'm using Swift as the language of choice? Let's say one is importing an Obj-C Pod into a Swift project, he needs a bridging header. With the other way around, using a swift cocoapod with obj-c, does the user need to do anything to make this run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, and hopefully the dependent framework doesn't remove his framework (its very rare they do it)
2. The bridging header is fine unless you use advanced generics (inheritance of a base generic class) as methods might not be available while converting to Objective-C.

Comment: So it is in fact possible, that somebody is deleting a pod from cocoapods while others are using it?

Comment: It is not possible to delete the pod at all, they can only deprecate it.

Comment: It can be both deleted from the CocoaPods specs repo, or someone could take down the source code ( which is why we recommend keeping your pods folder in source control https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control )